# RichText adding images in AdminJs

Tags: image, admin, richtext, tiptap, adminjs

I need help. I have a deadline very soon, so I don’t have time and I need your help. I have a website that has content that I create and change through a built-in component in adminjs richtext. It is built on the basis of TipTap. While editing text in richtext, I insert an image. I save the changes. Everything works fine, I can even see the saved image. But if suddenly I want to change my uploaded image and click change, richtext will open but without the images I previously uploaded. There can be 10-15 such images in one richtext. And there are 5-6 such richtext components.

adminjs version 7.4.1. Why is this happening? And how can this be fixed?